# vmware workstation server on linux without gui: import VM instead of creating new

Tags: linux, vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-server

I have a linux (debian) server without gui and installed vmware workstation[1]. I use the server service (shared VMs) to be able to run VMs. I can successfully connect from my Windows PC to the Server to create new VMs on the server and run them.

What I am missing is the possibility to import VMs: Instead of just be able to create new VMs with the connected console on the server I like to run already existing VMs already placed on the server - even if they are already placed in the 'shared VMs folder', they cannot be opened and started. - I can only create new VMs. Does anybody know, if this is possible in any way?

Does anybody know, if there is a way e.g. by a shell command on the server to 'Share' an already existing VM?

[1] I used version 9 and updated now to version 12. It seems that there are not more possibilites related to the server / console / VM management.

Comment: Down vote and no comment? This is unfair! What is missing in my post? It is a real situation and a problem...

Comment: There are a rash of those today. The only thing I can think of it that's because someone thinks this question should go to the StackExchange sites [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/) or [**ServerFault**](http://serverfault.com/). Shake it off, it's only 4 points - the kids that downvoted obviously didn't have the integrity to help.

Comment: Oh, I see... yes it is not a typically programming question... so my fault. However, it is funny, some minites ago, I just got a good answer...

Comment: A very good answer. I always look to pickup vmware tips. I have esxi running that I manage via ssh and I hate having to resort to windows as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may edit directly the file `/etc/vmware/hostd/vmInventory.xml`.
There you can copy a `<ConfigEntry>` section and change the path to the new .vmx file.

A complete `vmInventory.xml` may look like this:

```
<ConfigRoot>
  <ConfigEntry id="0000">
    <objID>1</objID>
    <vmxCfgPath>/mnt/vm/debian/debian.vmx</vmxCfgPath>
  </ConfigEntry>
  <ConfigEntry id="0001">
    <objID>2</objID>
    <vmxCfgPath>/mnt/vm/win10/win10.vmx</vmxCfgPath>
  </ConfigEntry>
  <ConfigEntry id="0002">
    <objID>3</objID>
    <vmxCfgPath>/mnt/vm/ubuntu/ubuntu.vmx</vmxCfgPath>
  </ConfigEntry>
  <ConfigEntry id="0003">
    <objID>4</objID>
    <vmxCfgPath>/mnt/vm/win7x32/win7x32.vmx</vmxCfgPath>
  </ConfigEntry>
</ConfigRoot>
```

Comment: OK, this works; however, do not forget to perform `/etc/init.d/vmware-workstation-server restart`. Otherwise, editing the fill will not have any effect until next reboot of physical machine.